# Mostrar al usuario los datos de MYSQL de manera eficiente?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, vb.net, datatables, dataset

Estoy mejorando un programa que tengo en VB .NET actualizando referencias, simplificando métodos y mejorandolo en general.

Mi problema es que a la hora de cargar la información en un DataSet, aparte de que cuando hago "Scroll" el refresco de la información del dataset va como si tuviera "lag" o lento ya que se me queda en blanco o tarda en aparecer la información.

Además ciertas consultas a MySQL donde tengo que recuperar mucha información ( mas de 7k rows) directamente me da error de timeout, entiendo que no es conveniente aumentar mas el tiempo de espera para traerme la información... Así que me imagino que es un problema de como esta diseñada la consulta.

Dejo por aquí una de las consultas y como lo meto en el dataset para mostrarlo en la interfaz.

```
Sub Consultar()
    Dim l_where As String = ""
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim rs As New DataSet

    For Each l_control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf l_control Is GroupBox Then
            For Each l_subcontrol In l_control.Controls
                If Procesar_campo(l_subcontrol, l_where) = False Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        Else
            If Procesar_campo(l_control, l_where) = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If chb_anuladas.Checked = False Then

        If l_where = "" Then
            l_where = "where activa <> '3' "

        Else
            l_where = l_where & " and activa <> '3' "
        End If
    End If
    If chb_canceladas.Checked = False Then

        If l_where = "" Then
            l_where = "where activa <> '8' "

        Else
            l_where = l_where & " and activa <> '8' "
        End If
    End If

    If l_where = "" Then
        l_where = "where tipo = '" & G_TIPO & "'"
    Else
        l_where = l_where & " and tipo = '" & G_TIPO & "'"
    End If

    If Not cmb_estado.SelectedValue = 99 Then
        If l_where = "" Then
            l_where = "where activa = " & cmb_estado.SelectedValue
        Else
            l_where = l_where & " and activa = " & cmb_estado.SelectedValue
        End If
    End If
    If txt_referencia.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        Dim l_where_ref As String = ""
        Call Construir_condicion(l_where_ref, txt_referencia.Text, False)

        If l_where = "" Then

            l_where = "where (prototipo,desarrollo) in (select prototipo,desarrollo from prototipos_p where referencia " & l_where_ref & ")"
        Else

            l_where = l_where & " and (prototipo,desarrollo) in (select prototipo,desarrollo from prototipos_p where referencia " & l_where_ref & ")"
        End If
    End If
    If Abrir_sesion() Then
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from prototipos_c " & l_where & " order by activa desc , prototipo", cn)
        da.Fill(rs, "proto")
        MessageBox.Show("select * from prototipos_c " & l_where & " order by activa desc , prototipo")
        dgv_prototipos.Columns.Clear()
        Dim l_checkbox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn With {
            .HeaderText = "Elab.Proto",
            .Name = "genera",
            .DataPropertyName = "genera",
            .TrueValue = 1,
            .FalseValue = 0
        }

        dgv_prototipos.Columns.Add(l_checkbox)

        Dim l_checkbox2 As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn With {
            .HeaderText = "Rev.Semanal",
            .Name = "valid_dise",
            .DataPropertyName = "valid_dise",
            .TrueValue = 1,
            .FalseValue = 0
        }

        dgv_prototipos.Columns.Add(l_checkbox2)

        dgv_prototipos.DataSource = rs.Tables("proto")

        dgv_prototipos.Columns("prototipo").HeaderText = "Prototipo"
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("oficial").HeaderText = "Mod.Oficial"
        If G_TIPO = "C" Then
            dgv_prototipos.Columns("desarrollo").HeaderText = "Desarrollo"
        Else
            dgv_prototipos.Columns("desarrollo").HeaderText = "Modelo"
        End If

        dgv_prototipos.Columns("fecha").HeaderText = "Fecha"
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("fecha").Visible = True
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("usuario").HeaderText = "Usuario"
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("tipo").Visible = False
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("notas").HeaderText = "Notas"
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("notas_patronaje").HeaderText = "Notas Patronaje"
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("colec").HeaderText = "Colec"
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("borrado").Visible = False
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("imagen").Visible = False
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("imagen_colores").Visible = False
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("activa").Visible = False
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("fecha_valid_dise").HeaderText = "F.Rev.Semanal"
        dgv_prototipos.Columns("fecha_valid_dise").Visible = True
        lbl_resultados.Text = "Resultados: " & dgv_prototipos.Rows.Count
    End If
End Sub
```

Espero que alguien pueda aclararme como seria la manera optima de realizar este tipo de consultas en vb net.

Muchas gracias anticipado.

Comment: Deberias asegurar contra inyeccion SQL esas consultas; imagina que pasaria si le paso el valor a us_proto `'; DROP ALL TABLES ---`

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta @J.Salas. La verdad no me habia preocupado de esas cosas ya que es un programa local, pero tambien es verdad que nunca he investigado como he de hacerlo.

Comment: y el segundo query yo lo agilizaria un poco pasando la subquery (el select entre parentesis) a un JOIN

Comment: 7k filas no es nada.. si tarda, es por otras cosas... las cuales no podemos saber magicamente. Igual, traer 7000 filas es raro, un usuario no ve tantas filas pero bueno... Otras cosas, porque usas datasets, que tiene un monton de overhead, en lugar de EF o si fuera mucho mejor dapper? las consultas tienen los indices que corresponden? la verdad, salvo contarte muchas cosas, no hay forma de darte una respuesta sin saber realmente que pasa...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación y tu comentario @gbianchi, justamente eso es parte de lo que busco con esta pregunta, es correcto utilizar datasets o datagridviews? Este programa esta echo con VS 6 y net framework 3.5. Ahora que lo estoy actualizando a una versión mas reciente, veo que otros programas no tienen ese problema de visualización de los datos en la interfaz, entiendo que las consultas hasta cierto punto obviamente se pueden mejorar pero el problema esta en como muestro yo los datos.

Comment: y todo lo que te podemos decir, es opinion y experiencia personal... para lo que vos queres, hay que hacer un analisis de mil cosas.. no se puede dar una respuesta, porque alguien te va a decir que si, y otro te va a decir que no, y cual es la respuesta correcta? este tipo de cosas, es mejor hablarlas en el [chat]

Comment: Si agregas a tu consulta `LIMIT 100` ¿sigue tardando?

Comment: @Sal el problema no es la consulta ( ya que ya estube viendo como optimizarlas y las cosas que deberia hacer como buenas practicas, el problema esta en como se muestran los datos en el dataset o datagrid cualquiera que sea. Gracias por tu aportación igualmente.

Comment: Que es exactamente lo que quieres mostrarle al usuario? 7000 filas de datos? podrias mostrarle las primeras 1000 o las ultimas 1000 filas y el usuario filtrara los datos que desee buscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ademas de optimizar las consultas, solucionó mi problema de renderizado lento de los datagridviews de mi aplicación, por si a alguien mas le sirve.

```
Private Shadows Sub DoubleBuffered(dgv As DataGridView, setting As Boolean)
    Dim dgvType = dgv.GetType()
    Dim pi As PropertyInfo = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Igualmente gracias por los consejos a quienes comentarion.

Saludos.